# Parsing string in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Here's a string that I'm trying to parse in python

```
    s1="One : Two : Three : Four  Value  : Five  Value  : Six  Value : Seven  Value : Eight  Value :"
```

Can someone tell me a re function I can use to parse the above string so that s1 becomes as follows without any ':'

```
One

Two

Three

Four Value

Five Value 

Six Value

Seven Value

Eight Value
```

I've tried making use of strip, lstrip and rstrip after spliting the string by using the following code but I don't get the format I need

```
    res1=s1.split(' : ')
```

UPDATE:
Thanks a lot for your answers but the output I'm getting looks like this whether I use

1->

```
    for index in s1:
      print index
```

or....

2->

```
    pprint(s1)
```

OUTPUT:

O

n

e

:

T

w

o

:

T

h

r

e

e

:

F

o

u

r

V

a

l

u

e

:

F

i

v

e

V

a

l

u

e

:

S

i

x

V

a

l

u

e

:

S

e

v

e

n

V

a

l

u

e

:

E

i

g

h

t

V

a

l

u

e

:

Comment: Not a regex, but would do the job `filter(lambda x: x != '', [item.strip() for item in s1.split(':')])` or `[item.strip() for item in s1.split(':') if item.strip() != '']` or `[item for item in map(lambda x: x.strip(), s1.split(':')) if item != '']`

Comment: That's pythonic and concise. Post it as an answer!

Comment: actullay, your original code should work. have you tried print s1.split(' : ')

Comment: he has a " :" at the end. That sort of messes up.

Comment: Do you want the output in a single string, or in an array?

Comment: In an array where each line is one element

Comment: This `for index in s1:` should be `for index in res1:` in `1`

Comment: Please have a look at the UPDATE i've included in my question :) @DJV

Comment: @DavidZwicker could you look at it too? :)

Comment: @NidhiPaul have a look at my previous comment

Comment: Your output looks like you are doing `s1.split('')`, not `s1.split(':')`.

Comment: Or because you are doing `for index in s1:` instead of `for index in res1:`

Comment: thank you so much. it works just fine now =) especially @DJV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
'\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1.split(':'))
```

returns

```
One
Two
Three
Four  Value
Five  Value
Six  Value
Seven  Value
Eight  Value
```

If you need extra empty lines:

```
'\n\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1.split(':'))
```

Comment: I tried that but the result I get is this:
O
n
e
 
:
 
T
w
o
 
:
 
T
h
r
e
e
 
:
 
F
o
u
r
 
 
V
a
l
u
e
 
 
:
 
F
i
v
e
 
 
V
a
l
u
e
 
 
:
 
S
i
x
 
 
V
a
l
u
e
 
:
 
S
e
v
e
n
 
 
V
a
l
u
e
 
:
 
E
i
g
h
t
 
 
V
a
l
u
e
 
:

Comment: @NidhiPaul - pasting such strings as a comment won't help much.

Comment: @NidhiPaul did you forget the `.split(':')`?

Comment: @DJV - right, that is the only way OP could get such a result.

Comment: @DJV forget it where exactly?

Comment: @NidhiPaul do you write `'\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1)` instead of `'\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1.split(':'))`

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension approach (for diversity reasons and cause it's the only answer that doesn't leave a blank item at the end). Either of these:

```
filter(lambda x: x != '', [item.strip() for item in s1.split(':')])
[item.strip() for item in s1.split(':') if item.strip() != '']
[item for item in map(lambda x: x.strip(), s1.split(':')) if item != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re
 re.split(r'\s*:\s*', s1)
```

And, slightly more efficiently, if you have to do a lot of splitting...

```
 import re
 split_re = re.compile(r'\s*:\s*')
 split_re.split(s1)
```

And this will also work. It would be interesting to do a speed test.

```
 [a.strip() for a in s1.split(':')]
```

These will all get you an array containing each word. If you want a string containing multiple lines with a blank line between each word, you can use `'\n\n'.join(foo)` for each of them to get that string. But this also works:

```
 import re
 split_re = re.compile(r'\s*:\s*')
 res1 = split_re.subn('\n\n', s1)[0]
```

Testing shows though that:

```
 res1 = '\n\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1.split(':'))
```

is actually the fastest, and it's certainly the prettiest. And if you want to avoid the blank line at the end from the final ':' that doesn't have anything after it:

```
 res1 = '\n\n'.join(a.strip() for a in s1.split(':')).strip()
```

Comment: Btw, that leaves a '' at the end

Comment: @DJV: So it does. Not sure if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Me neither :) Just saying.

Comment: @DJV: I fixed the blank line at the end problem through brute force. :-) Unfortunately, it will have a side effect if there are a bunch of empty sections at the beginning or end. It will strip of *all* the blanks. And it's even less clear if that's the right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1/ If you want a string:

From your split() :

```
res1 = '\n'.join(res1)
```

Other solution:

```
res1 = s1.replace(' : ', '\n')
```

2/ If you want a list:

```
res1 = [item.strip() for item in s1.split(':')]
```

[...] will return a list containing your strings. Check "List Comprehensions" in [http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is: `res1 = ' '.join(s1.split(':'))` if you want a single row string, else you should try: `res1 = '\n'.join(s1.split(':'))`